# To convert currency from US to UK in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I tried this code to display but I need AngularJS to automatically convert currency:

```
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">

  default currency symbol ($): {{0.00 | currency}}

  custom currency symbol (£): {{0.00 | currency:"£"}}

 </div>

 <script src="index.js"></script>
 <script src="uk-locale.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Andrey said, you should build your own custom filter to handle the currency conversion.
Here's a simple demo of how I would build such a thing:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('currency', function() {
    var defaultCurrency = '$';

    return function(input, currencySymbol) {
        var out = "";
        currencySymbol = currencySymbol || defaultCurrency;

            switch(currencySymbol) {
                case '£':
                    out = 0.609273137 * input; // google
                    break;

                default: 
                    out = input;
            }

        return out + ' ' + currencySymbol;
    }
});
```

#### check the [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LFN8x/1/)

Comment: I extended @gion_13's answer to support exchange rates provided in template: 

    Your price is {{money | currency}} (or {{money | currency:'EUR':1.3}})

Result: 

    Your price is 100 USD (or 130 EUR)

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ekus/yn0otcaq/1/**

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs currencyFilter just formats output. If you want actually convert currency, you need to make custom [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), for example.

Here is possible example:

```
angular.module('myFilter', []).filter('currencyConverter', [function() {
   function convert(inputValue, currecyId) {
       // Your conversion code goes here
   }

   return function(inputValue, currencyId) {
      return convert(inputValue, currencyId);
   }
});
```