# AngularJS - Currency exchange filter with external output

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a filter based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973757/to-convert-currency-from-us-to-uk-in-angularjs). I want to be able to switch from one currency to the other by switching a select input with an ng-click on it, but I'm failing to get the input into the filter.

My html is:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    you have, {{money | currency}}...<br><br>
</div>
<select>
    <option ng-click="currencySymbol = 'USD'; currencyRate=exchange.usd.rate">USD<option>
    <option ng-click="currencySymbol = '£'; currencyRate=exchange.pound.rate">£<option>
    <option ng-click="currencySymbol = '€'; currencyRate=exchange.euro.rate">€<option>
</select>
```

And the Angular part:

```
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.money = 100;
    $scope.exchange = [
        {"usd":{"rate":1}},
        {"pound":{"rate":0.702846}},
        {"euro":{"rate":0.885055}}
    ];
})

.filter('currency', function() {
    var defaultCurrency = 'USD';
    return function(input, currencySymbol, currencyRate) {
      var out = "";
      currencySymbol = currencySymbol || defaultCurrency;
      currencyRate = currencyRate || 1.00;

      out = input * currencyRate;

      return out + ' ' + currencySymbol;
      }
 });
```

You can check the JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Joe82/dLLtzqyr/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few updates here:

- First off, your dropdown is located outside of the controller
- You could use the ng-options directive to clean up your select menu
- You have ng-click on each option which doesn't work well with the complex model you are trying to maintain
- If you pass the whole selected option into the filter, you can manage everything from that one scope variable keeping the data in one place

Here is a working example
http://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/dLLtzqyr/1/

This will be your simplified html:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  you have, {{money | currency: selectedCurrency}}...
  <br>
  <br>
  <select ng-model="selectedCurrency" ng-options="item as item.label for item in exchange">
  </select>
</div>
```

And your js:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  // controller here
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.money = 100;
    $scope.exchange = [{
      label: "USD",
      rate: 1
    }, {
      label: "£",
      rate: 0.702846
    }, {
      label: "€",
      rate: 0.885055
    }];

    $scope.selectedCurrency = $scope.exchange[0];
  })

.filter('currency', function() {
  return function(input, selectedCurrency) {
    var out = "";

    out = input * selectedCurrency.rate;

    return out + ' ' + selectedCurrency.label;
  }
});
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You define 3 parameter in your filter currency. Whenever you use your filter, you need to give these parameters to your filter. In your case :

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      you have, {{money | currency:currencySymbol:exchange[2].euro.rate}}...<br><br>
</div>
```

In AngularJS world, you call your filter after the `|` and you use `:` as a separator for parameters (the first parameter input is always given implicitly).

To make the debug easier, you can add this in your filter :

```
 return function(input, currencySymbol, currencyRate) {
      console.info('currency parameter', input, currencySymbol, currencyRate);
```

Please note that I hardcoded the parameter currencyRate because it's not handy to retrieve with the way you store your array.