# Extend Angular Template Syntax

Tags: angular, templates, syntax, extend

I am looking for some advice on how to extend the Angular templating syntax.

Reason : I am new to Angluar, and find it great so far, however some time ago I wrote my own simple templating system which I would like to retrieve some of the functionality from within the scope of Angular. It was written for a project I was working on at the time and has the same {{ }} syntax.  The difference is my system allowed me to insert directives between the two opening braces which act in the same way as Angulars filters I.E :

{${1000000}}  =  {{1000000 | currency}}  = $1,000,000

As I understand it, in order for Angular to support British pounds, a custom filter would need to be written such as the one found here :

[To convert currency from US to UK in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973757/to-convert-currency-from-us-to-uk-in-angularjs)

I would like to provide the ability to do the following :

{GBP{1000000}  = £1,000,000
{CAD{1000000}  = C$1,000,000

And so on, for about a dozen or so different useful cases I frequently use with my templating system. Things like {l{THIS WILL BE LOWER CASE}} {U{{this will be upper case}} and so on.

It seems to me that I could write a simple pre-processor for the page which converts my syntax to Angular syntax prior to Angular being instantiated, but I feel that that approach may be both inefficient and inelegant.

Of course I could just get over it and type the more verbose Angular filter directives out, but as an ulterior motive to doing this I'm also curious about the Angular internals and how they work.

Any help will be most appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With regex and custom pipes you can definitely get what you're looking for. First, you'd need to write a custom pipe - https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Second, you'd have to define some way to do all the formatting and transforming that you require. I'm not entirely sure what it is exactly you are trying to write a pipe for, but all you need to know is that the `transform` function will do all of the work for you in the end.

If you could give a clearer example of what you're trying to pipe, I'd be happy to help further.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!

Examples... the simplest thing would be for 

{${1000000}} to have the same effect as writing {{1000000 | currency}}

Where the number could be a variable or a string etc.


Other utils I have in my templating engine are {.{className}} where the output in the dom would be class="className" and {#{someId}} where the output is id="someId". Basically I'm looking to golf the template syntax a bit and allow for a filter to be specified by a shortcode inbetween the opening brackets. 

Hope that makes it more clear, once again thanks for your response!

Comment: From what I know, Angular won't understand things unless they're surrounded in **two** curly braces. I don't think you will be able to do what you want. `{${1000000}}` will not be recognized by Angular and you'll just get plain HTML of that text.

Comment: Yeah that's why I was thinking to do some sort of pre-processing prior to instantiating Angular, so I can have a doc with the syntax I like transform into Angular syntax before running. Whilst I'm confident that would work, I don't think that's a very elegant solution and I was hoping someone might know of some internal mechanisms in Angular which allow you to customise the way it processes template directives.